# Content lost on JavaSparkContext parallelize

Tags: java, apache-spark, lucene

I have a classical 'Singleton' pattern in order to share JavaSparkContext in multiple classes. I want to parallelize a list which contains a custom class named ColumnCombinationBitset. As the name indicates it is consisted of an OpenBitSet serializable field.
Even though the initial list does contain my bitsets, it seems that they are empty after I use JavaSparkContext parallelize method to turn the list into an RDD.

I believe that I have done something wrong on the serialization of the OpenBitSet wrapper class, but I am not sure if this is the case. I have implemented hashCode, equals for condition checking, readObject,writeObject for serialization and I have put an empty-argument constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create Broadcast wrappers of ColumnCombinationBitset. After this I was able to successfully create the rdd by using parallelize.